# Create Desktop Shortcut for any Application ubuntu 17.10

Tags: virtualbox

i can make shortcut application on desktop on ubuntu 16.04
I couldnt make shortcut application on desktop on ubuntu 17.10.

How do i make shortcut for example chrome on my desktop on ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 0):

This is the GUI-only approach:

1. Open Nautilus (*"Files"*) and browse to *Other Locations > Computer > /usr/share/applications*
2. Search for the application you need (e.g. *Firefox*), select and copy with right click context menu

   [image]
3. Paste that icon on your desktop

   [image]
4. On first run select *Trust and Launch* on the message window

   [image]
5. The launcher is now trusted and will be displayed with the application's icon

   [image]